# Jackson custom KeyDeserializer for Map, excluding entries where key is null

Tags: java, json, jackson

The custom key deserializer in my POJO as follows:

```java
@JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = MyCustomKeyDeserializer.class)
@JsonInclude
private Map<T, @Range(min = 0, max = 100) Integer> ratios;
```

However, I have a situation where a key that was previously valid, is no longer valid and would like to offer backward compatibility.

For example, if the code used to accept the keys `AGE` and `HEIGHT` and would like to start excluding `HEIGHT`, the JSON object `{"AGE": 30, "HEIGHT": 60}` would be deserialized to just `{"AGE": 30}` in the map

The way I tried to approach it was by returning a `null` value from the `MyCustomKeyDeserializer` class.  However, the map is now ending up with an entry containing `null` as one of the keys. Is there a way to exclude null keys from the map? Or a different approach to providing such behavior?

The code for the serializer is along the lines as follows:

```java
public class MyCustomKeyDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer {

    private Map<String, Object> registry;

    @Override
    public Object deserializeKey(final String key, final DeserializationContext ctxt) 
       throws IOException {
        return registry.get(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what is the key name is, you can just use `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"HEIGHT"})
@JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = MyCustomKeyDeserializer.class)
private Map<T, @Range(min = 0, max = 100) Integer> ratios;
```

Comment: Is there a more dynamic way of providing these properties to ignore instead of hardcoding them?

Comment: You can modify `MapDeserialiser` using `SimpleModule` and [BeanDeserializerModifier](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/BeanDeserializerModifier.html) class. You need to override `modifyMapDeserializer` method and change original deserialiser by setting ignorable fields by calling `setIgnorableProperties` method on deserialiser.

Comment: Good idea.  Is there any way of not doing for all maps?  The key that should be ignored in this map should not be ignored in other places

Comment: Right now it is not possible without implementing custom map deserialiser. Default `MapDeserialiser` checks only `JsonIgnoreProperties`, it does not check `filters feature`. You can register custom deserialiser using `JsonDeserialize` annotation like for `MyCustomKeyDeserializer`.